# Lightning force:inputField with filter issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, forceinputfield

I have a lightning component that uses the force:inputField element for a lookup.  The lookup field has a filter applied to it.  I have the filter field displayed on my component, but when I set the value and type into the lookup box, no data is returned.  If I remove the filter from the field, I do get results back.

Here is my lightning component.

```
<aura:component controller="LocationController" >
<aura:handler event="c:newClassCodePayrollEvent" action="{!c.showModal}"/>

<aura:attribute name="classCodePayroll" type="ClassCodePayroll__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'ClassCodePayroll__c' }"/>
<aura:attribute name="locationId" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="state" type="String" default=""/>

<force:outputField aura:id="locationId" value="{!v.classCodePayroll.Location__c}" class="slds-hide"/>

<div class="slds">
    <div aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-hide" aura:id="newClassCodePayrollDialog">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Class Code Payroll</h2>
                <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close" iconName="utility:close" alternativeText="Close" onclick="{!c.hideModal}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--pull-padded-medium">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal--medium">
                        <ui:outputText class="slds-form-element__label" value="State"/>
                        <force:inputField aura:id="stateInput" value="{!v.classCodePayroll.State__c}"/>
                        <ui:outputText class="slds-form-element__label" value="Class Code"/>
                        <force:inputField aura:id="classCode" value="{!v.classCodePayroll.ClassCodeT__c}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal--medium">
                        <lightning:input label="Estimated Payroll" name="estimatedPayroll" value="{!v.classCodePayroll.EstimatedPayroll__c}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.hideModal}">Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.save}">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--hide" aura:id="backdrop"></div>    
</div>
```

The lookup field is:

```
<force:inputField aura:id="classCode" value="{!v.classCodePayroll.ClassCodeT__c}"/>
```

And the filter field is:

```
<force:inputField aura:id="stateInput" value="{!v.classCodePayroll.State__c}"/>
```

Here is an image of the component WITHOUT the filter on the field - which does return results. (Notice two "5552" results for different states)
[image]

Here is what it looks like when I apply the filter:
[image]

I can't post an image of the standard Salesforce create window - but suffice to say it has the filter applied correctly.

Comment: Have you found solution for this issue?